# Is there a way to check a version of excel workbook for latest version?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I have a main excel workbook that I have users work off of. The function of this excel workbook is to copy and create other workbook using macros ect. This copy is located on a network drive where everyone can access it. The problem is, if someone has copied this version to their desktop and then I later come up with a new version of this main workbook, the old one that the person has copied to their desktop will not have the latest updates to the macros and ect. Is there a way to check or prevent the old one from being able to run the macros or for the old workbook to work?

Comment: Set the source of the copy to be a network folder that only you manage for the macros

Comment: all the copy is done on a network folder. The macros are within the main workbook.

Comment: is it possible that when the main excel file creates a new workbook for that new workbook to check the main excel for it's last modified date so that if it is modified at a earlier date the workbook being created will kill the process therefore the old main excel will not work?

Answer (score 3):

**Step 1:** You can write a macro that will check for the main file in a network location. You can use `Dir` or `FSO` to do this:

**Dir:**

```
Sub Test_File_Exist_With_Dir()
    Dim FilePath As String
    Dim TestStr As String

    FilePath = "\\Server\test\book1.xlsm"

    TestStr = ""
    On Error Resume Next
    TestStr = Dir(FilePath)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If TestStr = "" Then
        MsgBox "File doesn't exist"
    Else
        MsgBox "File exist"
    End If

End Sub
```

**FSO:**

```
Sub Test_File_Exist_FSO_Late_binding()
'No need to set a reference if you use Late binding
    Dim FSO As Object
    Dim FilePath As String

    Set FSO = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")

    FilePath = "\\Server\test\book1.xlsm"

    If FSO.FileExists(FilePath) = False Then
        MsgBox "file doesn't exist"
    Else
        MsgBox "File exist"
    End If

End Sub

Sub Test_File_Exist_FSO_Early_binding()
'If you want to use the Intellisense help showing you the properties
'and methods of the objects as you type you can use Early binding.
'Add a reference to "Microsoft Scripting Runtime" in the VBA editor
'(Tools>References)if you want that.

    Dim FSO As Scripting.FileSystemObject
    Dim FilePath As String

    Set FSO = New Scripting.FileSystemObject

    FilePath = "\\Server\Ron\test\book1.xlsm"

    If FSO.FileExists(FilePath) = False Then
        MsgBox "File doesn't exist"
    Else
        MsgBox "File exist"
    End If

End Sub
```

---

**Step 2:** You can have it check the last modified date of that file which can be used to determine if a newer version exists.

```
FileDateTime("\\Server\test\book1.xlsm")
```

**Sample Result:** 6/1/2016 7:40:18 PM

---

**Step 3:** If a newer version exists, you can display a message box to the user to copy the new version from the network drive and close the workbook. (I wouldn't recommend automation to copy/paste from the network location to the user's workstation since this could easily get messy and without this, it still does what's needed)

```
MsgBox "A new version of this file exists on the network share. Please use the new version. This workbook will now close."
ActiveWorkbook.Close savechanges:=False
```

---

**References:**

- [Test if Folder, File or Sheet exists or File is open](http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s9/win003.htm)
- [MS Excel: How to use the FILEDATETIME Function (VBA)](https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/filedatetime.php)
- [How to suppress "Save Changes" prompt when you close a workbook in Excel](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/213428)

Comment: If a user has the a older version of the main excel file copied onto their desktop and is using it just like the main one on the network, how is this suppose to prevent the user from being able to create new workbook from the macro within the main excel file?

Comment: it's almost like when the user is creating the new workbook which creates from a excel template, when the macro that opens/creates the new workbook from the template > have a macro within that template to check the main excel file that is doing the creation to see if it's the newest one if not end the macro process.

Comment: You would need to update the current main excel file on the network share  with the above code modified the way you need and just this time, inform ALL users that the file is updated and to get the new version from the network share. Once that is done, any other subsequent updates to the mail excel file on the network share will be detected by the excel file that the users have copied